# Using <Picker> dialog but programatically (trigger press worst case)

Tags: react-native

I need to offer a list of options in a modal. Android has `<Picker>` which on click presents the items. `iOS` has `Alert`.

On Android I want to use the `<Picker>` in `dialog` mode functionality without having to create an element, just like the `Alert` API on iOS. Is this possible?

Anyway to trigger a "press" on the `<Picker>` to get its dialog modal?

Comment: As far a I know, Alert and Picker offer two different features. I assume that by "without creating an element" you mean without creating a Component class. Could you explain a little more what you need?

Comment: @sfratini thanks for the comment. I need an API exactly like `Alert` on android. On Android the `Alert` API does not offer unlimited buttons. The `dialog` that `<Picker>` opens on Android does offer unlimited buttons, I just need that dialog opened by programtic/method rather then GUI press.

Comment: Gotcha. See my answer shortly.

Answer (score -2):

So, this is a way of doing what you want. You could show/hide the picker by wrapping it in another Component. This is an old example I used once:

```
const MyPicker = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { displayed: true };
  },
  show() {
    this.setState({ displayed: true });
  },
  hide() {
    this.setState({ displayed: false });
  },
  render() {
    if (this.state.displayed) {
      return <Picker {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</Picker>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @sfratini! I tried this in a `<TouchableOpacity>` and I scaled the `<Picker>` so its so big it covers the view and the "drop down arrow" is out of bounds so not visible. It doesn't work if in its anything that has an `onPress`. So I had to put in plain `<View>` but lose the opacity changing. Thanks I'll just do this for now even though its not ideal and I wanted to dodge using the GUI. Thanks sir!

Comment: Not quite understood what you mean. Feel free to post more info/code in the question and I can tell you if there is a workaround.

Comment: @Noitidart I rolledback your edit. It had nothing to do with my answer. If you want, post a new one on your name.

Comment: your answer is incorrect though. I accepted it in hopes you would improve it based on my follow up question.